# Are there Hats on IOTA Stackexchange too?

Tags: feature-request

Hi I just got some Bonus Item on Bitcoin Stackexchange. It's a Hat! [image]

Will we have hats on the IOTA Stackexchange, too?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the hats are here on IOTA StackExchange, too. I earned the Retro Fan hat on this site (by upvoting an old question, I believe).

The hats are the same on every StackExchange site, and here is a list of all hats for Winter Bash 2018: [Winter Bash 2018 Hat list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319838/winter-bash-2018-hat-list)